# Autoconf from /etc/network/interfaces is not working

Tags: ipv6, embedded-linux

I want to disable autoconf of IPv6 for which I am making entries in `/etc/network/intefaces` file as below. Before making this changes I use "`ifdown eth0`"

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
address <ipv6_address>
netmask 64
autoconf 0
```

After this I use "`ifup eth0`". But, still I am getting IPv6 global address based on MAC address.

Comment: What distro you run?

Comment: linux version 2.6

Comment: The question is about OS, such as Debian, CentOS, so on.

Answer (score 0):

First, try fixing the typo:

```
iface inet6 eth0 static
```

The second and third parameters are reversed. This should read:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
```

Comment: I have done that already. According to man page of /etc/network/intrerfaces, if inet6 static is there, it will disable autoconf. But, I am getting global IPv6 address based on MAC which indicates autoconf is enable. So to disable it, I have tried this. But, still I am getting global address based on MAC.